# Save images in SQL image field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, image, upload

I am using javascript to save a image in SQL database, the problem is that in the table the data type for save images is "image" and i dont know how i can upload the images or what are the correct conversion to upload these images.

Comment: _I am using javascript to save a image in SQL database.._ Do not store images in the db... put them on the filesystem as images are files

Comment: please give more details, currently it is not clear you are using javascript as client to send data to a service backed by database, or you are directly interacting with database with node js. both cases will cause different solutions.

Comment: @B001 DO store them in the database, not separate. It's much more convenient. You just need to make sure your server has enough memory to have the images ready on request.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth never ever

Comment: The db is not mine, It's from my boss an i am not allowed to change it. I am forced to save images in the db

Comment: @marmeladze yes, i am using a rest service to send the information, that is a nodejs service

Comment: You have to base64 encode the image data and then store it in a `mediumtext` or `longtext` field - depending on how big your images probably are.

Comment: which part are you dealing with? the node part or the client part

Comment: @marmeladze i am working in the client part

Comment: then you have nothing to do with saving images to anywhere. you can only send data. the rest of processing (parsing, saving to anywhere etc.) must be dealt with server side code.

Comment: @marmeladze yes but i need send the image with the correct format i cant only send the image path, you know what i mean?
i need send in the json the correct format of the image for the "image" field in the db table. The acceptable format to save it in the database, and this part is in the client

Comment: how does the server-side code save image? how does they accept image? do you have a documentation, or at least some source code to identify this? in any case, you will have to use `btoa` function. it will encode image to text. i hope server side code knows how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the server this method receives a json with correct img format "sql.IMAGE"

```
exports.GuardarPaciente = async function(req, res) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", CORS);
try {
    //String de Conexion
    sqlConfig.database = "DCR_" + req.body.Code;

    //Login Connection
    let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
    let result = await pool.request()
    .input('PERIMG', sql.IMAGE, req.body.PERIMG)
    .execute('SP_MANT_PERSONA_V2')
    res.send(result.output);
}
catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
}
finally{
    sql.close();
}
```

Comment: @marmeladze this is the implementation in the server